# Unable to delete files through Terminal

Tags: files, osx, rm

More recently, I have been using `rm -r /path/to/file` to delete files, but when deleting from certain locations, I get the error: `override rw-r--r--  root/admin for filename?` I have tried entering `y`, but I get the error: `rm: filename: Permission denied`. I have also tried `rm -rf` and `yes | rm -r` with the error `rm: filename: Permission denied` again. Is there any way to bypass this strange issue? My operating system is Mac OSX Yosemite, and I am using Terminal.

Comment: It probably has to do with the permissions on the directory not the file.

Comment: I believe that is true @mdpc, I am asking how to override that I guess. I probably should have made that more clear.

Comment: A solution would be to change the directory permission.

Comment: What are the permissions on `/path/to`, does `chflags` show anything interesting on any of the files or directories involved, and you might need to boot in rescue mode to delete some of the really restricted files in recent OS X releases.

Comment: And that is with the shift key, correct?

Comment: Which files, precisely? IIRC recent versions of OSX make some parts of the system read-only even to root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your file was created using by the root user so in order to modify o delete this file you would need to authenticate as root using `sudo`. To do this simply type:

```
sudo rm -rf path/to/file
```

Here, `rm -rf` stands as *remove recursively* so that if `path/to/file` is a directory all its content will be removed. Your machine will ask you for your password. Consider that after this instruction, the files will be **completely removed!**.

Answer (score 1):

I have found on MacOS that:

```
chmod u+w FILE
rm -f FILE
```

or

```
chmod -R u+w DIR
rm -rf DIR
```

fixes some "Permission denied" problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to delete the folder with sudo.

```
sudo rm -rf foldername
```